# How to hide fields (input) by jQuery - Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I would like to show or hide fields depending on the value of another field. I was not able to find and implement the existing topics.

```
function selectService (){
   if($jquery('[id$=inField1]').val() == "value_1"){
       /* TODO Hide $id inField2*/
   }
}

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Informations">
       <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field1__c}" onchange="selectService();" id="inField1"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field2__c}" id="inField2"/>
</apex:form>
```

When the #inFields1 value = value_1, I want Hide #inField2. What are the best solution ? It must use the attribute 'rendered' ? Thank's

Comment: Have you tried to use `hide()` function of the jQuery? Like `$jquery('[id$=inField2]').hide();`

Comment: I just tried, but it doesn't hide the label.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rendered` attribute of the `apex:inputField`. So if the Object__c.Field1__c = value_1 it will be not shown at all:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="showHideField2" reRender="mySection"/>

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Informations" id="mySection">
       <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field1__c}" onchange="showHideField2();" id="inField1"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field2__c}" id="inField2" rendered="{!Object__c.Field1__c != 'value_1'}"/>
</apex:form>
```

The `apex:actionFunction` works like a normal javascript function but can do reRender of the visualforce components.

Or you can use a jQuery solution for that as well. You will need to define an label for the outputField and hide that label together with a field:

```
function selectService (){
   if($jquery('[id$=inField1]').val() == "value_1"){
       $jquery('[id$=inField2]').hide();
       $jquery('[id$=inField2Label]').hide();
   }
   else{
       $jquery('[id$=inField2]').show();
       $jquery('[id$=inField2Label]').show();
   }
}

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Informations">
       <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field1__c}" onchange="selectService();" id="inField1"/>     
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Object__c.fields.Field2__c.label}" id="inField2Label"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field2__c}" id="inField2"/>
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, the first solution seems to me, but I can't identify all working.

Comment: @SimonG What's the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the attribute `reRender` and why conditions `!=`

Comment: And why not use the attribut `showHeader` ?

Comment: I solved my problem. I took your first code `hide()` applied on pageBlockSection. But your code interested me and I will servire.